# Singleton design potential leak

Tags: ios, singleton, memory-leaks, analyzer

I have downloaded a library off of github and have noticed that in the main singleton of the library there is a possible leak in this bit of code:

```
+(DDGameKitHelper*) sharedGameKitHelper
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (instanceOfGameKitHelper == nil)
        {
            [[DDGameKitHelper alloc] init];
        }

        return instanceOfGameKitHelper;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Now obviously there is no release or autorelease anywhere so I must do it but how and in what way properly? I have looked at various Singleton design patterns on the Internet and they just assign, in this case, instanceOfGameKitHelper to the alloc and init line.

Anyway how would I properly fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more modern way to setup singletons is like this:

```
+ (DDGameKitHelper *)sharedGameKitHelper {
    static DDGameKitHelper *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{ instance = [self new]; });

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I like it, simple and concise AND it silences the warning. Plus its easier to read.

Comment: @iBradApps As noted in the other answer, the warning was because you never assigned the object to your variable.

Comment: Ok I understand, I upvoted both answers bc they both helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

A singleton, by definition, is created once and never released.  Think of it sort of like a global variable.

Take a look at this document from Apple:  [Cocoa Core Competencies - Singleton](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html) for more details.

Or for their example (at the bottom of the page):  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

I usually use @rmaddy's method though.  Of course, even that way, you are still assigning the variable and never releasing it since it is still a singleton.

Comment: Is there any way to silence the warning then without silencing the others in my app?

Comment: @iBradApps Yes, actually assign the allocated object to the `instanceOfGameKitHelper` variable.

Comment: Yeah, the code that you posted won't even work.  Change `[[DDGameKitHelper alloc] init];` to `instanceOfGameKitHelper = [[DDGameKitHelper alloc] init];`.

Comment: If the author assigned the static variable inside of the init method, then it will work just fine.  Of course, the more modern version is preferred these days :).